# undefined method `each' Problem/Question?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

```
<% @company.contacts.each do |contactall| %>
        <% contactall.each do |contact| %>
            <%= contact.name %>
            <%= contact.position %>
            <%= contact.email%>
            <%= contact.telephone%>
            <%= contact.source%>
            <%= contact.company_id%>
        <% end %>
<% end %>
```

What's wrong with it?
I want to display each contact separately if i do take out `<% contactall.each do |contact| %>`

and do contact.name i get a bunch of the contacts name's that are associated with the company. help?

I want them all separate.]

The fix:

```
<% @company.contacts.each do |contact| %>
            <b>Name:</b>
            <%= contact.name %>
            <b>Position:</b>
            <%= contact.position %>
            <b>Email:</b>
            <%= contact.email%>
            <b>Telephone:</b>
            <%= contact.telephone%>
            <b>Source:</b>
            <%= contact.source%><br />
<% end %>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What do you mean separate? This?

```
<% @company.contacts.each do |contact| %>
  <div>
    <%= contact.name %>
    <%= contact.position %>
    <%= contact.email%>
    <%= contact.telephone%>
    <%= contact.source%>
    <%= contact.company_id%>
  </div>
<% end %>
```